# Sort a list based on a string- Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I want a list to be sorted as if by the sorted(list) method, but by a string. What I mean is, instead of sort by 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', be able to control it. Like, sort in the order of 'zyabxwcdvueftsghrqijpoklmn', but do this based on any 26-letter string you put in. How would I do this?

The sorted(list) method sorts a list into alphabetical order. If I want reverse alphabetical order, that's also fairly straightforward. But say I want a completely custom priority of letters? The default sorts the list in the order `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. What if I could input a string, like `'zyabxwcdvueftsghrqijpoklmn'`, and I could sort a list based on this priority? So, given `['moose', 'apple', 'zebra', 'penguin']`, and the string `'zyabxwcdvueftsghrqijpoklmn'`, I would get `['zebra', 'apple', 'penguin', 'moose']`, because of the order the letters appear in the string.

Comment: You'll have to create your own algorithm to do this...also, as this question is worded, it's beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: See below Luke. It is actually extremely simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def make_sort_key(key_string):
    # make index
    index = {}
    for i,ch in enumerate(key_string):
        index[ch] = i
    # sort any char not in index following any char in index
    omitted = len(index)
    val = index.get

    def key_fn(s):
        return [val(ch, omitted) for ch in s]

    return key_fn
```

then

```
items = [
    "abcde",
    "fghij",
    "fghde"
]

items.sort(key = make_sort_key("gfiabdcej"))
```

results in

```
['fghij', 'fghde', 'abcde']
```

Comment: I think it is best to no reinvent the wheel. No offense, but I feel that my route is more efficient.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi - this answer does more than yours, correctly implementing the lexical sort. Test both on `['fghde', 'fghij', 'abcde']` with `"gfiabdcej"` as the ordering string - a correct sort will put the `fghij` before `fghde`. It's also more efficient, although that doesn't matter for the kinds of data we see here - `index.get` on a dict is faster than `index` on a list.

Comment: Actually I fixed my code, now it is in fact, more efficient and it goes as far.